# How to add items to a lista without \n?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need get the text from each 'href' and add then to a a list. But I haven't been successful handling with scores of '\n'.

```
projects = soup.find_all('div', 
class_ = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ajustar_fonte')

numbers = []
for item in projects:
    numbers.append(item.text)

print(numbers)

['\n\r\n                                        Projeto de Lei\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        576\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6900\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Projeto de Lei\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        575\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6898\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Projeto de Lei\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        574\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6897\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Projeto de Lei\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        573\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6896\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Indicação\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        1769\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6895\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Requerimento de Pesar\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        91\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6894\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Indicação\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        1768\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6893\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Indicação\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        1767\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6892\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Indicação\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        1766\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6891\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n\r\n                                        Projeto de Lei\r\n                                        N°\r\n                                        572\r\n                                        /2019\r\n                                    Processo N°:\r\n                                    6890\r\n                                    /2019', '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n']
```

Comment: Can you provide a few samples of `projects`?

Comment: url = 'http://www3.al.es.gov.br/spl/consulta-producao.aspx'

Comment: Can't you just `.strip("\n")`  all the newlines and carriage returns where necessary?

Comment: or use re.sub or check whether the selector can be made more specific. Your list is called numbers but you appear to be adding long strings suggesting you could be more specific if just after a number. Including the html/url would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get('http://www3.al.es.gov.br/spl/consulta-producao.aspx', headers=headers)   
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')

projects = soup.find_all('div', 
class_ = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ajustar_fonte')

numbers = []
for item in projects:
    tmp = item.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').strip() # getting rid of newline and carriage return characters
    if tmp != "": # some items will be empty strings, skipping them 
        numbers.append(' '.join(tmp.split())) # replacing multiple spaces with one

for i in numbers:
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
Projeto de Lei N° 576 /2019 Processo N°: 6900 /2019
Projeto de Lei N° 575 /2019 Processo N°: 6898 /2019
Projeto de Lei N° 574 /2019 Processo N°: 6897 /2019
Projeto de Lei N° 573 /2019 Processo N°: 6896 /2019
Indicação N° 1769 /2019 Processo N°: 6895 /2019
Requerimento de Pesar N° 91 /2019 Processo N°: 6894 /2019
Indicação N° 1768 /2019 Processo N°: 6893 /2019
Indicação N° 1767 /2019 Processo N°: 6892 /2019
Indicação N° 1766 /2019 Processo N°: 6891 /2019
Projeto de Lei N° 572 /2019 Processo N°: 6890 /2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .text returns a string, maybe use this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

?